# command.MissingRole(missing_role) errorHandling

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, chatbot, python-3.8

Bad problem what is the solution?

```
@say.error
async def say_error(ctx, error):
    Missingrole = get(guild.roles, id=730356075689410570)
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRole(missing_role)):
        await ctx.send(f'`You dont have {Missingrole} role..')
```

Gives error:

> command.MissingRole(missing_role) errorHandling

Comment: You should read this about asking minimal, complete, and verifiable questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve 
what is @say  -
what is get   -

Answer (score 0):

`isinstance` can only tell whether or not `error` is a `MissingRole` object, not if it represents a specific missing role.  You should separate that outinto it's own check

```
@say.error
async def say_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRole):
        if error.missing_role.id == 730356075689410570:
            await ctx.send(f'`You dont have {error.missing_role} role..')
        else:
            await ctx.send("You are missing some other role")
    else:
        raise error  # if we can't handle the error, bubble it back up
```